# Why is this SQL Query causing an "Ambiguous column name" error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which fails to execute:

```
select p.PersonID, CreatedDate, * from dbo.Person p 
join dbo.PotentiallyFraudulentPeople pfp on p.PersonID= pfp.PersonID 
order by CreatedDate
```

The `Person` table has a PK of `PersonID` (int). The `PotentiallyFraudulentPeople` view is a query of the `Person` table joined with some other tables to decide if we trust a person or not. The `PotentiallyFraudulentPeople` view only has one column: `PersonID`.

When I try to execute this query, I get this error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'CreatedDate'.

I understand that this error is telling me that the `CreatedDate` column name is ambiguous and I need to preface it with my table's alias, 'p'.

This query works:

```
select p.PersonID, CreatedDate, * from dbo.Person p 
join dbo.PotentiallyFraudulentPeople pfp on p.PersonID= pfp.PersonID 
order by p.CreatedDate
```

What I don't understand is why I need to use the 'p' alias in the `ORDER BY` statement and not in the `SELECT` column list. Also, I don't understand why I need to use the table alias at all since the `PotentiallyFraudulentPeople` view doesn't even have a `CreatedDate` column.

Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and SSMS to execute the query.

**UPDATE**
Also, I tried removing the `CreatedDate` column from my `SELECT` column list and then the query no longer requires the 'p' alias in the `ORDER BY`. So this query works as well:

```
select p.PersonID, * from dbo.Person p 
join dbo.PotentiallyFraudulentPeople pfp on p.PersonID= pfp.PersonID 
order by CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are selecting the `CreatedDate` column twice.

1. Explicitly via `CreatedDate`.
2. Implicitly via `*`.

It doesn't know which occurence you want to sort on - and it obviously doesn't realize that both occurences refer to the same column.

Comment: This sounds like odd behaviour for SQL Server but it explains my problem. Thanks! I will accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Just had this problem and this was the cause, didn't realize this was an issue with the order by

Answer (score 8):

And the reason that the name is ambiguous is related to the fact that the order by clause allows use of alias names so p.CreateDt and *.CreateDt both alias to CreateDt.  Since order by allows alias names, it can't resolve

Answer (score 3):

You can add an alias to "CreatedDate" and sort it using the alias

```
select 
    p.PersonID, 
    CreatedDate [create_date], 
    * 
from 
    dbo.Person p join 
    dbo.PotentiallyFraudulentPeople pfp on p.PersonID= pfp.PersonID 
order by 
    [create_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which table that CreateDate came from. It means you have this column name in both tables. So either p.CreatedDate or pfp.CreatedDate.

Comment: FYI, you're responding to a question that was answered 4 years ago. Please keep in mind the post date when you answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your original query, another option is to explicitly define the column's position:

Rather than:

```
select id, name, *  from employee order by name
```

Try:

```
select id, name, *  from employee order by 2
```

**id** would be position 1

**name** is position 2, etc..