# SQL: ORDER BY "column" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, supabase

I run below sql query

```
SELECT *FROM
(SELECT * FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i WHERE d."userId" = u."userId" and d."diaryId" = i."diaryId") AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') AND "secretType" <> '비공개'
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

Then it returns proper data.

[image]

As you can see above, it has column `createdAt`

So I tried to order it with this column.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i WHERE d."userId" = u."userId" and d."diaryId" = i."diaryId") AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') AND "secretType" <> '비공개'
ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

Then it throws this below error.

> ERROR:  42702: ORDER BY "createdAt" is ambiguous LINE 4: ORDER BY
> "createdAt" DESC

Even though I checked that there's column named 'createdAt', why it says that createdAt is ambiguous?
What is the problem with my code?

+)

I also thought that `creaetdAt` is used in multiple tables.

So I specify createdAt should be coming from table alias `d` as below.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i WHERE d."userId" = u."userId" and d."diaryId" = i."diaryId") AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') AND "secretType" <> '비공개'
ORDER BY d."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

But this below error happens.

> ERROR:  42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "d" LINE 4: ORDER
> BY d."createdAt" DESC

Can you show me how to specify `createdAt` coming from table d with my code?

Comment: `ORDER BY` comes before `LIMIT` as noted in your previous question. It's not valid to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: There are multiple columns named createdAt, because you used `*` in the subquery *(more than one of the three source tables has a createdAt column)*. Instead of `*`, specify the columns you want, and the table each column is from.

Comment: @charlieface this is a different mistake

Comment: @Charlieface yeah I didn't changed code in this post only. in practical I make it before `LIMIT` but this above error occurs. I edit my post.

Comment: @MatBailie Then the duplicate should have been https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342271/why-is-this-sql-query-causing-an-ambiguous-column-name-error

Comment: @MatBailie I make it d."createdAt" before but it throws another error. please check edited post and explain me more.

Comment: `SELECT *` in the subquery is what needs fixing. Change it to `SELECT d.whatever, u.whatever, etc` to make sure each column name only appears once.

Comment: @MatBailie oh.. then I need to type all columns one by one. is that correct?

Comment: Outside the subquery, `d` isn't known, only the select list columns are exposed. I.e. the subquery returns a `"createdAt"` column. In your ORDER BY you should specify `a."createdAt"`. (However, if there's another createdAt column in one of the other tables, you have to take care of that too, e.g. only select one of them.)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT **d.createdAt** FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i WHERE d.userId = u.userId and d.diaryId = i.diaryId) AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') AND secretType <> '비공개'
ORDER BY d.createdAt DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

You did not specify which table to use for the "createAt" column.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the '*' in the first SELECT.

Try this and see if it the ORDER BY statement works:

```
SELECT createdAt    
FROM (
             SELECT * FROM diaries AS d, 
                           users AS u, images AS i
                      WHERE d."userId" = u."userId" and d."diaryId" = i."diaryId"
           ) AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') 
                    AND "secretType" <> '비공개'
ORDER BY 1 DESC    
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i WHERE d."userId" = u."userId" and d."diaryId" = i."diaryId") AS a
WHERE "phone" IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') AND "secretType" <> '비공개'
ORDER BY a."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "d" LINE 4: ORDER BY
> d."createdAt" DESC

The alias `d` is not recognized outside the subquery, you can use the alias of the derived table (`a` in your case) followed by the column alias without referring back to the original table alias `d` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT d.createdAt as createdAt_d, [other columns specied by aliases d,u and i]
  FROM diaries AS d, users AS u, images AS i 
  WHERE d.userId = u.userId and d.diaryId = i.diaryId
) AS a
WHERE phone IN ('010-3334-7167', '010-5628-2214') 
      AND secretType <> '비공개'
ORDER BY createdAt_d DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET (1 - 1) * 5
```